# How to sign out from Microsoft identity in a Blazor Server App?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, microsoft-identity-platform

In VS I've created a Blazor Server App from Microsoft's template. With Authentication Type: Microsoft identity platform.
When authenticated, application has 'Log out' hyperlink pointed to https://localhost/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignOut
On click it redirects to https://login.microsoftonline.com/... page that asks "Pick an account. Which account do you want to sign out of?".

How to programmatically sign out from my application that uses Microsoft identity, without asking an account?

I've tried

```
            app.Use(async (context, next) => {
            if (context.Request.Path.Equals("/logout", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                await context.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            }
            await next();
        });
```

but when refreshing the page, application logs in again automatically.
If I remove CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme parameter, then it begins to ask "Pick an account..."

Comment: I'm afraid it is not realizable..

Comment: Maybe I have to do something with token, to force Microsoft to forget that user is authenticated?

Comment: The reason supporting my idea is that per my searching and experience, microsoft identified this 'flow' to make all other app integrate the login module. And I remembered that I saw a similar question but may be related to azure ad sign out skip selecting account but hadn't got solution. This [link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/issues/126).